# Как я могу поворачивать 2d объект вокруг своей оси тачем в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно поворачивать объект вокруг своей оси.
Т.е. нужно поворачивать объект в то место ,где сейчас находится палец игрока(нужно что бы он поворачивался до того момента пока игрок не уберет палец с экрана.

У меня была одна идея.
1)Создать невидимый объект и перемещать его на место тача.
2)Поворачивать мой объект в сторону первого.

Но,скорее-всего,есть способ попроще.

Comment: Что-же там у вас такое, вообще не понимаю, а код, мы тоже должны представить сами? Что пробовали, что не получилось, за вас тоже надо написать нам?

Comment: С чем трудности?

Comment: По идее должно быть какое-то событие для татча по экрану. (Благо интернет должен помочь вам ) А затем вращайте ваш объект через Rotate.